# node js callback function is sometimes ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Hi I'm new in Node js and Postgresql, and try to get used to it. Still I have to modify nodejs code..

I defined a function that executes 2 SQL. Insert and update.
I put UPDATE statement inside callback function of INSERT like this

```
exports.requestwithdraw = function(depositId, amount, uowner, uaccf, uid, sum, wdcnt, callback) {

query('INSERT INTO public.cash(mode, value, requested, step, uid, uname, uacc, id, stname) VALUES (2, $1, now(), 1, $5, $2, $3, $4, $6);', [amount, uowner, uaccf, depositId, uid, '신청'], function(err, res) {
    if(err) return callback(err); // <--this INSERT always works.

    assert(res.rowCount === 1);
    query('UPDATE users set balance= $2,last_req=now() where id= $1', [uid,sum],function(err, res2) {
        if(err) return callback(err); // <--this UPDATE sometimes doesn't work

        assert(res2.rowCount === 1);
        callback(null);
    });
});
```

};

The second query for UPDATE mostly work well, but sometimes doesn't execute. I tried putting both statements inside the same query() method, but it was not allowed. 
If one succeed, the other also should succeed. If one of them fails, the other must not execute as well.

How can I make those both query work always together?

Comment: you mean database transactions?https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve something called transactions in SQL. 
In Nodejs, databases queries are asynchronous.
Try using query.on("row") and query.on("end") events to deal with this behaviour.
Given code block will make sure that the second query runs before the callback is called.
There is something called knex js which can be used to deal with transactions.

```
exports.requestwithdraw = function(depositId, amount, uowner, uaccf, uid, sum, wdcnt, callback) {

var query1 = query('INSERT INTO public.cash(mode, value, requested, step, uid, uname, uacc, id, stname) VALUES (2, $1, now(), 1, $5, $2, $3, $4, $6);', [amount, uowner, uaccf, depositId, uid, '신청'], function(err, res){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    assert(res.rowCount === 1);
});

query1.on('end', function(result){
    query2 = query('UPDATE users set balance= $2,last_req=now() where id= $1', [uid,sum], function(err, res2){
        if(err) return callback(err);
        assert(res2.rowCount === 1);
    });
    query2.on('end' function(result2){
        callback(null);
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems that query.on() removed from pg7